# Working to draw boundary around an object and the object is inside the image

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to draw a boundary around a object, say in this case a lesion object inside an image with plain background with not much noise. I had taken the image and read pixel values.

And tried calculating XY coordinates along the boundary of the object using active contour algorithm but the boundary drew are on edges of the whole image instead on boundary along the object inside, which I couldn't make it any better to get good coordinates. So can you please suggest me if there is any better way to find/draw boundary around object inside image or should i go for using openCV with Xcode better to make an ios app? Kindly suggest.

Comment: can you please post a sample image? it will also be useful to see the code you tried for solving the problem.

Comment: Great. Sample image, which I am trying to draw boundary around the object in the image : https://www.dropbox.com/s/c45hc2ph2kqot8m/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-19%20at%201.27.38%20PM.png?dl=0
Code, I have uploaded the same in dropbox for better view. I tried using active contour algorithm equation to detect XY coordinates along boundaries on the object inside the image. 
code link, swift file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6p4ff0wosynxmte/pixelRead.swift?dl=0

Is there a common error made on active contour method that it gives wrong XY coordinates ?

Comment: How tight should the boundary be? Do you expect actual segmentation? Bounding box? Something in-between?

Comment: I am not looking for accuracy right now. Any boundary near to the image would help me.

Comment: Can we have a short discussion over stackoverflow chat ? I would like to get information to catapult my work and there are really less people working on this.

Comment: Your end goal will have a huge impact on choosing an approach. But if the images all look somewhat similar to the one you posted, I would start with simple color based separation to foreground/background followed by foreground contour fitting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109723/discussion-between-rajesh-thevar-and-rosa-gronchi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried using OpenCV's active contours, but the fact you have near black and near white outline along the image edges probably doesn't help

(input image provided in the comments section above)
[image: input image]

(this is an opencv+python prototype)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('skin.png')
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
red = rgb_img[:,:,0]
height, width, channels = rgb_img.shape
```

create mask and apply flood-fill

```
mask = np.zeros((height+2, width+2), np.uint8)
flooded = red.copy()

flags = 4 | cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY
cv2.floodFill(flooded, mask, (8, 8), 1, 2, 2, flags)
plt.imshow(1-mask)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: candidates mask]
a bit of a morphological cleanup

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
omask = cv2.morphologyEx(1-mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
plt.imshow(omask)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: filtered candidates mask]
find contours:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(omask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )
```

find largest area contour:

```
largest_contour = []
largest_area = 0
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > largest_area:
        largest_area = area
        largest_contour = contour
```

display result (a choice of rectangle and outline):

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)
cv2.drawContours(rgb_img, [largest_contour], -1, (0, 128, 128), 3)
cv2.rectangle(rgb_img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

This is a very straightforward and simple solution which is not perfect. It can be improved with [grabcut](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#grabcut) (at the cost of computational complexity) or other techniques.